MacOS Gone After Bootcamp Install
After installing Windows 8.1 on my Mac Mini 2011 (macOS High Sierra 10.13.6) using bootcamp everything seemed fine and working until one day I wanted to switch back to macOS. I used Option Restart but it only showed bootcamp so then I tried using bootcamp assistant but once again it just booted back into windows after clicking "Restart In MacOS". Please help -- I'm desperate
here.
Update 6: So i got USB and for some reason i just deleted windows and reinstalled it but now its done the exact same thing so i was wondering must i make a new question or keep updating this one?
Here is the updated outputs
-bash-3.2# diskutil list disk0
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
  #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
  0:                                                   *120.0 GB   disk0

-bash-3.2# gpt -r show disk0
gpt show: error: bogus map
gpt show: unable to open device 'disk0': No such file or directory 

 -bash-3.2# fdisk /dev/disk0
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 14593/255/63 [234441648 sectors]
Signature: 0x0
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      

-bash-3.2# export LC_CTYPE="C"
-bash-3.2# dd if=/dev/disk0 bs=512 skip=40 count=1 2>/dev/null | vis -fcw
\M-kX\M^PBSD\s\s4.4\0\^B\^A\s\0\^B\0\0\0\0\M-p\0\0\s\0\^P\0\0\0\0\0\0@\^F\0O\f\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\^B\0\0\0\^A\0\^F\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0)\^A\^W\M-VpEFI\s\s\
\s\s\s\s\s\sFAT32\s\s\s\M-z1\M-@\M^N\M-P\M-<\0|\M-{\M^N\M-X\M-h\0\0^\M^C\M-F\
\^Y\M-;\a\0\M-|\M-,\M^D\M-@t\^F\M-4\^N\M-M\^P\M-k\M-u0\M-d\M-M\^V\M-M\^Y\r\nNo\
n-system\sdisk\r\nPress\sany\skey\sto\sreboot\r\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0U\M-*\

-bash-3.2# export LC_CTYPE="C"
-bash-3.2# dd if=/dev/disk0 bs=512 skip=409640 count=1 2>/dev/null | vis -fcw
v\^E\M^M5\M-@7r\^X\^A\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\M-U\240\^S\^B\0\0\0\0\^A\0\0\M^@\0\0\0\0NX\
SB\0\^P\0\0u\M^D\M-_\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\^B\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0VlC\M-.d\M-cB|\M-;\M-j\^\]\M-B3\M-~\M-@\M-B\M-L{\^B\0\0\0\0\M-V\240\^S\^B\0\
\0\0\0\^X\^A\0\0\^Xl\0\0M\M^C\M-_\0\0\0\0\0\M-i\^Q\M-_\0\0\0\0\0\^B\0\0\0\^D\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\^B\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\^D\0\0\0\M-A\M-L{\^B\0\0\0\0h\M-"\^E\0\0\0\0\0\
\^A\^D\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0d\0\0\0\M-'\M-<\^B\0\0\0\0\0'\^Y\^B\0\0\0\0\0)\^Y\^B\
\0\0\0\0\0x\M-7\^B\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\

-bash-3.2# export LC_CTYPE="C"
-bash-3.2# dd if=/dev/disk0 bs=512 skip=117597136 count=1 2>/dev/null | vis -fcw
\M-kR\M^PNTFS\s\s\s\s\0\^B\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\M-x\0\0?\0\M^?\0\M-Pc\^B\a\0\0\0\0\
\M^@\0\M^@\0/\M-T\M-v\^F\0\0\0\0\^B\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\M^H\M-.U\0\0\0\0\0\M-v\0\0\0\
\^A\0\0\0\v\M-f\M-s:\^^\M-t:\M-j\0\0\0\0\M-z3\M-@\M^N\M-P\M-<\0|\M-{h\M-@\a\^_\
\^^hf\0\M-K\M^H\^V\^N\0f\M^A>\^C\0NTFSu\^U\M-4A\M-;\M-*U\M-M\^Sr\f\M^A\M-{U\
\M-*u\^F\M-w\M-A\^A\0u\^C\M-i\M-]\0\^^\M^C\M-l\^Xh\^Z\0\M-4H\M^J\^V\^N\0\M^K\
\M-t\^V\^_\M-M\^S\M^_\M^C\M-D\^X\M^^X\^_r\M-a;\^F\v\0u\M-[\M-#\^O\0\M-A.\^O\0\
\^D\^^Z3\M-[\M-9\0\s+\M-Hf\M^?\^F\^Q\0\^C\^V\^O\0\M^N\M-B\M^?\^F\^V\0\M-hK\0+\
\M-Hw\M-o\M-8\0\M-;\M-M\^Zf#\M-@u-f\M^A\M-{TCPAu$\M^A\M-y\^B\^Ar\^^\^Vh\a\M-;\
\^VhR\^Q\^Vh\t\0fSfSfU\^V\^V\^Vh\M-8\^Afa\^N\a\M-M\^Z3\M-@\M-?\n\^S\M-9\M-v\f\
\M-|\M-s\M-*\M-i\M-~\^A\M^P\M^Pf`\^^\^Ff\M-!\^Q\0f\^C\^F\^\\0\^^fh\0\0\0\0fP\
\^FSh\^A\0h\^P\0\M-4B\M^J\^V\^N\0\^V\^_\M^K\M-t\M-M\^SfY[ZfYfY\^_\^O\M^B\^V\0f\
\M^?\^F\^Q\0\^C\^V\^O\0\M^N\M-B\M^?\^N\^V\0u\M-<\a\^_fa\M-C\M-!\M-v\^A\M-h\t\0\
\M-!\M-z\^A\M-h\^C\0\M-t\M-k\M-}\M^K\M-p\M-,<\0t\t\M-4\^N\M-;\a\0\M-M\^P\M-k\
\M-r\M-C\r\nA\sdisk\sread\serror\soccurred\0\r\nBOOTMGR\sis\scompressed\0\r\nP\
ress\sCtrl+Alt+Del\sto\srestart\r\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\M^J\^A\M-'\^A\M-?\^A\0\0U\M-*\

LC_CTYPE="C"; dd if=/dev/disk0 bs=512 count=1 2>/dev/null | vis -fcw
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\M^?\M^?\M^?\M-n\M^?\M^?\M^?\^A\0\0\0\M-/K\
\M-y\r\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0U\M-*\

LC_CTYPE="C"; dd if=/dev/disk0 bs=512 skip=36 count=1 2>/dev/null | vis -fcw
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\M^?\M^?\M^?\M-n\M^?\M^?\M^?\^A\0\0\0\M-/K\
\M-y\r\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0U\M-*\


Can you boot to Internet Recovery and post the output from diskutil list disk0, gpt -r show disk0 and fdisk /dev/disk0?

AnotherRandoGuy453112: Add the output from the commands given in "Update 1" of my answer to your question.

I edited my answer. See Update 3.

I edited my answer. See Update 4.

Which command was the last command? I am just trying to make sure.

Make sure you can boot to both macOS and Windows.

I assume you entered the commands while booted in macOS Recovery. Do you do so?

I finished adding update 5.

I am not sure I understand your last edit. You say you lost the USB flash drive. Can you not get some other flash drive to use?

Boot to Internet Recovery. Enter the following command.
fdisk -e /dev/disk0

This command is interactive. Type in the entries given in the first column of the table given below.



Entry
Type
Comment




s 1
Command
Set the identifier of first table entry


ee
Parameter
Identifier for GPT


q
Command
Quit edit of current MBR, saving current changes


y
Parameter
Confirm to save and quit




Update 1
Add the following output to your question.
export LC_CTYPE="C"
dd if=/dev/disk0 bs=512 skip=40 count=1 2>/dev/null | vis -fcw
dd if=/dev/disk0 bs=512 skip=409640 count=1 2>/dev/null | vis -fcw
dd if=/dev/disk0 bs=512 skip=117597136 count=1 2>/dev/null | vis -fcw

These commands output the header of the FAT32 EFI volume and APFS  container where macOS is stored. Basically, I am following the instructions given in this answer. Although at this point, I am not suggesting you use the linked answer.

Update 2
This update provides the steps to rebuild the GUID Partition Table (GPT) used by macOS. This will require temporarily erasing the Master Boot Record (MBR). This MBR contains both boot code and the partition table used by Windows.
The commands below backup the MBR (sector 0) to an unused location (sector 36).
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
dd if=/dev/disk0 count=1 bs=512 seek=36 of=/dev/disk0

The commands below overwrites the MBR with zeros.
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
dd if=/dev/zero count=1 bs=512 of=/dev/disk0

The commands below initialize the MBR and create a new empty GPT. Note that the gpt destroy disk0 command may produce the message gpt destroy: disk0: error: device doesn't contain a GPT, which you can ignore.
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
gpt destroy disk0
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
gpt create disk0

The commands below add the EFI, APFS and BOOTCAMP partitions to the GPT.
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
gpt add -i 1 -b 40 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B disk0
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 117187496 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
gpt add -i 3 -b 117597136 -s 116839472 -t EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7 disk0

The commands below restore the MBR from the copy saved at sector 36.
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
dd if=/dev/disk0 skip=36 count=1 bs=512 of=/dev/disk0


Update 3
I do not know precisely what the damage is with respect to the GPT. Therefore, I cannot exactly predict what the output from the gpt destroy disk0 command will be. You posted a different message than I predicted may occur. However, if you enter the next two commands given below and the gpt create disk0 command does not produce an error message, then you can proceed and enter the rest of the commands given after the gpt create disk0 shown in Update 2.
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
gpt create disk0


Update 4
This have been known to be referred to as the Nuclear Option. When all else fails, then write zeros over the entire MBR and the GPT. If the commands below succeed, then you can proceed and enter the rest of the commands given after the gpt create disk0 shown in Update 2.
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
dd if=/dev/zero count=34 bs=512 of=/dev/disk0
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
dd if=/dev/zero seek=234441615 count=33 bs=512 of=/dev/disk0
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
gpt create /dev/disk0


Update 5
The first two commands of Update 2 backed up the MBR (sector 0) by copying the sector to sector 36. I assume you did this successfully. The last two commands of Update 2 copy the backup (at sector 36) back to the MBR (sector 0). I assume you did this successfully.
However, apparently at some point after successfully entering the gpt create /dev/disk0 command, the commands to back up the MBR were executed again. This overwrote the original back up. I gave no instructions to do this. I assume you thought this was necessary to repeat.
So, at this point, the data stored in the MBR, which is needed to boot Windows, has been lost and there is no usable backup. Below is a list of what is missing.

The MBR partition table entries used by Windows.
The 32-bit disk signature. This is basically a random number. If this value changes, then the hidden C:\Boot\BCD file may need to be rebuilt. (BCD stands for Boot Configuration Data.)
The MBR boot code used to boot Windows.

The steps to repair are given below.

Repair the MBR partition table.
Enter the command given below from macOS Recovery.
fdisk -f /dev/disk0 -e /dev/disk0

The command given above is interactive. Type in the entries given in the first column of the table given below.



Entry
Type
Comment




e 1
Command
Edit first table entry


ee
Parameter
Identifier used for GPT


n
Parameter
Do not edit in CHS mode


1
Parameter
Partition offset in sectors


409639
Parameter
Partition size in sectors


e 2
Command
Edit second table entry


ff
Parameter
Identifier used for APFS


n
Parameter
Do not edit in CHS mode


409640
Parameter
Partition offset in sectors


117187496
Parameter
Partition size in sectors


e 3
Command
Edit third table entry


7
Parameter
Identifier used for NTFS


n
Parameter
Do not edit in CHS mode


117597136
Parameter
Partition offset in sectors


116839472
Parameter
Partition size in sectors


f 3
Command
Flag third table entry as bootable


p
Command
Print loaded MBR partition table


q
Command
Quit edit of current MBR, saving current changes


y
Parameter
Confirm to save and quit



If sucessful, then the output from fdisk /dev/disk0 should appear as shown below. (Note: The values in the cyl, hd and sec columns may be different.)
Disk: /dev/disk0 geometry: 14593/255/63 [234441648 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   2 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
 2: FF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  117187496] Xenix BBT
*3: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 117597136 -  116839472] HPFS/QNX/AUX
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused


Build a bootable Windows installer.

Note: If you have a Windows 8.1 or 10 DVD you can use the DVD. Otherwise, do the following.

Boot to macOS and use the Disk Utility to erase an 8 GB or larger flash drive. Below are the options to select.

If necessary, download a Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 ISO from Micrsoft. Mount the ISO, then use the Finder to copy all the files to the flash drive. When finished, eject the ISO volume.

Boot from the Windows installation medium.

Note: When booting, the Mac will not have access to the Windows Support Software available from Apple. I do not think you will need this software. However, if you encounter problems, then let me know.

Start or restart your Mac and immediately hold down the option key until the Mac Startup Manager icons appear. Boot from the DVD icon labeled "Windows" or boot from the external drive (flash drive) icon labeled "EFI Boot".

Add MBR boot code and replace the BCD.
When an image similar to the one below appears, press the key combination shift+F10 to open a Command Promt window.

Enter the commands given below. If the bootrec /rebuildbcd command prompts for input, enter the letter a followed by pressing the return key.
bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr
c:
cd \boot
attrib -s -h -r bcd
if exist bcd.old del bcd.old
ren bcd bcd.old
bootrec /rebuildbcd
exit

Next, do the following in the order presented.

Select the "Next" button.
Select "Repair your computer".
Select "Turn off your PC".



